# Python / ElementTree: following-sibling error (working in xpath tester)

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I have a simple XML document (actually ENML for Evernote) as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note>
   <div>Here is the Evernote logo:</div>
   <div>
      <en-media type="image/png" hash="a54fe8bcd146e20a8a5742834558543c" />
   </div>
   <div>
      <br />
   </div>
   <div>
      <en-todo />
      Task 1
   </div>
   <div>making it a bit harder</div>
   <div>
      <en-todo />
      Task 2 | 2016-12-31
   </div>
   <div>
      <br />
   </div>
   <div>
      This is another to-do
      <en-todo />
      in an awkward place
   </div>
</en-note>
```

I'm trying to use Xpath to access the text immediately after the `en-todo` tags. My code is:

```
parsed_note = ElementTree.fromstring(note_content)
for todo in parsed_note.findall('en-note//en-todo/following-sibling::text()[1]'):
    print todo.text
```

I've tested this using the Xpath tester at freeformatter.com - it seems to work, but only when I remove the `<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">` tag from the XML - I assume this is a quirk of the tester. The output is:

```
Text='Task 1'
Text='Task 2 | 2016-12-31'
Text='in an awkward place'
```

This is exactly as anticipated and desired.

When I attempt to run the code in Python, I get: `SyntaxError: prefix 'following-sibling' not found in prefix map`.

I suspected this may have been the same quirk as the tester and removed the file type tag, but the same error persists.

I'm using the standard parser:

```
import defusedxml.lxml as lxml
from lxml import etree as ElementTree
```

Where am I going wrong - is my xpath statement flawed, or is there some other reason for this that I'm missing?

EDIT: @Tomalek has provided a solution that works, using the Python `tail` function instead of the full xpath. Given the comments from @alecxe that the docs referenced are not for lxml, I will leave this open incase anyone wants to venture an idea about why the original problem exists when there should be a full xpath implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this answer is targeted at `xml.etree.ElementTree`. The similar, but more advanced `lxml.etree` module has full XPath support, but the method shown below works there as well.

---

Straight from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath), emphasis mine:

> #### 19.7.2. XPath support
>
> This module provides limited support for XPath expressions for
>   locating elements in a tree. **The goal is to support a small subset**
>   of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of
>   the module.

You can work around it by doing part of the traversal in Python.

In this case it's particularly easy because there's a convenient [`tail` property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) you can use. Other cases require more work.

```
parsed_note = ElementTree.fromstring(note_content)
for todo in parsed_note.findall('.//en-todo'):
    print todo.tail
```

You will have to `.strip()` whitespace from the returned value.

Comment: Thanks, apologies I hadn't seen this part of the documentation. I've tried your method - it removes the error, but doesn't seem to return anything (possibly because the text is not within the tags itself - I'll work some more to try to do this in python).

Comment: @HO the referred docs are for `xml.etree.ElementTree` while you are using `lxml.etree` which has the full XPath support..

Comment: A slight modification to your solution returns the correct result - I needed to change the xpath to `'.//en-todo'` - the `.tail` function then worked as expected.

Comment: @alecxe Ah, I always end up confusing the two. It should work in both though.

Comment: @HO Added that bit to the answer. If you work with lxml.etree you should have better XPath support, as Alex says.

Comment: Marked as answer since this is what I used - though the `.xpath` solution seems to work also.

Comment: The other answer is better suited for the module you use. Keep in mind that you don't have to jump through as many hoops to use XPath in lxml.etree, but lxml.etree is backwards-compatible to xml.etree.ElementTree.

Answer (score 3):

You should have used the `xpath()` method:

```
for todo in root.xpath('//en-note//en-todo/following-sibling::text()[1]'):
    print todo
```

Also note - I've added the `//` at the beginning and removed the `.text` - you've already got the text nodes - they don't have a `.text` attribute.

Comment: My code already has 2x `::`. Calling the xpath() method removes the error in my question, but returns no content.

Comment: @HO gotcha, updated with a working code. Hope that helps.